# How to split a string and assign each word to a new variable?

Tags: c#

I'm making a credit card processing form. The field in question is Name: (first and last).

What would some C# code look like that would take the text from a text box and split it, then assign each word (in this case first and last name) into two new strings?

E.g. `txtName.Text = "John Doe"`

After split

```
string fName = "John";

string LName = "Doe";
```

Comment: Be careful of people with double barreled names or people that enter their middle name

Comment: Am I the only one who is worried when someone in charge of building a credit card processing form doesn't understand the basics or string manipulation? I can only hope this is for a homework assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split the text on a character or string into a string array, and then pull the individual parts of the name out of the array. Like so:

```
string[] nameParts = txtName.Text.Split(' ');

string firstName = nameParts[0];
string lastName = nameParts[1];
```

But why not just have a separate text box for each part of the name? What if somebody puts their full name in the text box (i.e. you'd have three parts, not just two).

Comment: All you can do is answer the question in this case though.  This is a "give me teh codez" request.

Comment: Someone deleted their comment... now mine makes no sense.

Comment: @spender: agreed

@cory: passing a string (" ") to split won't work, needs to be a char (' ')

Comment: No problem, just waiting for my frame grabber board to download new firmware :)

Comment: The point about somebody using a middle name/initial is very good and should not be missed. This is why forms are so specific, rather than being one giant text field, like typing in your address free-form; it's much easier to get the user to parse the data for you than it is to guess at how they want you to parse it.

Comment: Authorize.net asks for First Name and a Last Name, not a middle initial. Like so : post_values.Add("x_first_name", "John");

                post_values.Add("x_last_name", "Doe"); Also, I plan to make two text boxes, I was just curious how to do it since I was thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] names = txtName.Text.Split(' ');
string fName = names[0];
string LName = names[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

it helps you to split a string in a part

`string FullMobileNumber = "+92-342-1234567";
          string[] mobile = FullMobileNumber.Split('-');
          _txtCountryCodeMobile.Text = mobile[0];
          _MobileCodeDropDown.SelectedValue = mobile[1];
          _txtEmployeeMobileNumber.Text = mobile[2];`

Answer (score 0):

String.Split returns an array, so... just assign from the array.