# How to parse this from a text file

Tags: c#

I am having a problem parsing the below example from a text file. What I am attempting to do is read the entire text file and then split the file up so each number is an individual element.

So it goes from this:

```
[466 474 482]

[24 8 29]

[50 46 3]
```

To this

[466], [474], [482], [24, [8], [29], [50], [46], [3]

My plan was to read the text by using ReadAllLines and then split the numbers individually using the Split method like so

```
string[] textFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"path");
string[] textFile2 = { };

for (int i = 0; i < textFile.Length; i++)
{
     textFile2 = textFile[i].Split(' ');
}

foreach (string number in textFile2)
{
     Console.Write(number + " ");
}
```

but I end up with this [50] [46] [3].

Comment: textFile2 is overriden every time, so it always contains last read row.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420366/how-to-split-a-string-and-assign-each-word-to-a-new-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing `textFile2` content for every line you read. Try using a `List<string>` instead.

```
string[] textFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"path");
List<string> textFile2 = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < textFile.Length; i++)
{
    textFile2.AddRange(textFile[i].Split(' '));
}

foreach (string number in textFile2)
{
    Console.Write(number + " ");
}
```

If your file really looks like that, with square brackets and blank lines, this may help you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fzBU4W

Comment: Shouldn't it be `AddRange` at the place of `Add`?

Comment: @CNuts Yes! Thanks!

Comment: Wow thanks. Can I ask what is the difference between AddRange and Add?

Comment: `Add` adds a single value to the list, while `AddRange` adds multiple values at once. In this case, you are splitting `textFile[i]`, so it's returning multiple values (an array). More info on MSDN: [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I'll also check out the link :)

Comment: You're welcome! Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Regex for such stuff.

Make sure you call Regex namespace at top of your code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Define a Regex instance as static field - it is good idea if you'll use this in high frequency.

```
public static Regex extractNumberRegex = new Regex("([\\d]+)[\\s]?");
```

The example below defines extension methods within a static class. 
First, let's extract the numbers from a String.

```
public static List<String> extractNumbers(this String source)
{
   List<String> output = new List<string>();

   MatchCollection mchCol = extractNumberRegex.Matches(source);
   foreach (Match mch in mchCol)
   {
       output.Add(mch.Value);
   }
   return output;
}
```

Your main method (here as extension too):

```
public static List<String> extract(this String path)
{
    String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    foreach (String ln in lines)
    {
       List<String> numers = ln.extractNumbers();
       String reformatLine = "";
       foreach (String num in numers)
       {
           reformatLine = reformatLine + "[" + num + "] ";
       }
       reformatLine = reformatLine.Trim();

       Console.WriteLine(reformatLine);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate input array and then split by char.

```
string[] textFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"path");
string concatInput = String.Join(" ", textFile);
string[] textFile2 = concatInput.Split(' ');

foreach (string number in textFile2)
{
     Console.Write(number + " ");
}
```

if you would like to remove the brackets [] you can do something like this...

```
string concatInput = String.Join(" ", textFile).Replace('[', ' ').Replace(']', ' ');
string[] textFile2 = concatInput.Split(' ').Where(x => x != "").ToArray();
```